# Browserstack for applications

Tags: android, ios, browserstack

I just wonder if there is some program or anything like Browserstack for app testing? not just web testing.

Or like an app simulator where I can try apps on different Android/iOS devices that I don't have. Thanks!

Comment: You could use Genymotion to emulate many devices.

Answer (score 0):

BrowserStack itself is coming up with app testing solutions using real devices. This is currently in beta and you can get in touch with the team.

Answer (score 0):

Its out now App Automate for Automation and AppLive for App testing and choosing your device.
https://www.browserstack.com/app-live